# Managing multiple login schema for site - need advice

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, facebook-graph-api, twitter-oauth

I want to set up my site to allow people to sign in using a facebook account. But in the near future I would also want to allow a provision to allow people to sign up using twitter, linkedin, even their open id accounts if they have one. However I need to set up my system so that a user may be able to login using whatever way he wishes and yet be able to maintain all his logins with his one account.

I have a users table which has the basic details:

```
USERS:
ID|NAME|EMAIL|PASSWORD
```

And think I should set up a logins table in this case like:

```
USERS_LOGINS
USER_ID|LOGIN_TYPE|LOGIN_ID
```

like in the second table if he signs up using facebook the Login type would read Facebook and id would be his fb id and so forth.

Is there any kind of service that already does this for you or any open source code I can use? My application is being built on the zend framework

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Janrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage). It will probably be the fastest and easiest way to support multiple login types.